# installing trusted execution engine interface driver error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, asus-laptop

I have an **ASUS X551MA** notebook and recently I downgraded it to windows 7 from windows 8. After I installed every driver I can find from Asus.com I encountered a problem installing a driver called '**Trusted Execution Engine Interface**'. Though it installed without any errors, It still shows up with yellow warning triangle in Device Manager. Please help?

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the device?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!  I contacted support and they said go back to Windows 8.

The solution was to get all the Microsoft Updates!

After that, the issue goes away!

It was disappointing to have ASUS state they don't support Windows 7 and to go back to Windows 8!